# Range of error in truncated division $\lfloor\frac{a\pm 1}{b\pm 1}\rfloor$

Tags: fractions, ceiling-and-floor-functions, natural-numbers

With $a,b\in\mathbb{N}^+$, $b > 1$ and $2\lfloor\log_2(b+\Delta_b)\rfloor\ge\lfloor\log_2(a+\Delta_a)\rfloor$ where $\Delta_n\in\{-1,0,1\}$ is my guess that
$$x + \Delta_x = \left\lfloor\frac{a+\Delta_a}{b+\Delta_b}\right\rfloor$$
correct? If the difference would be restricted to the numerator it would be
$$\left\lfloor \frac{a - 1}{b} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b - 1}{b} \right\rfloor -1$$
and
$$\left\lfloor \frac{a + 1}{b} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} + \frac{1}{b} \right\rfloor$$
respectively if I remember it right but the denominator is involved, too. So, how do I (dis)prove my assumption?

**Edited for clarity:**

$\Delta_n$ is meant to be a variable, so with all possible variations of the division the outcome is one of $x + 0$, $x - 1$, or $x + 1$ where $x + 0$ is the outcome of $\lfloor (a + 0 / (b + 0) \rfloor$. My assumption is that for all of the variations
$\lfloor(a+1)/(b+1)\rfloor$,
$\lfloor(a+1)/(b+0)\rfloor$,
$\lfloor(a+1)/(b-1)\rfloor$,
$\lfloor(a+0)/(b+1)\rfloor$,
$\lfloor(a+0)/(b-1)\rfloor$,
$\lfloor(a-1)/(b+1)\rfloor$,
$\lfloor(a-1)/(b+0)\rfloor$,
$\lfloor(a-1)/(b-1)\rfloor$, the result $x'$ is at most one unit away from  $x = \lfloor (a + 0 / (b + 0) \rfloor$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest and smallest numbers that can be expressed as $\frac{a+\Delta_1}{b+\Delta_2}$ with $\Delta_1,\Delta_2\in\{-1,0,1\}$ are $\frac{a+1}{b-1}$ and $\frac{a-1}{b+1}$, respectively. We can calculate that
$$\frac{a+1}{b-1}-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a+b}{b(b-1)}$$
and
$$\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a-1}{b+1}=\frac{a+b}{b(b+1)}.$$
If these differences are both at most $1$, that is, if $a\leq b^2-2b$, then the floors of any of these and $\frac{a}{b}$ can't differ by more than $1$; if $\lfloor y\rfloor\geq\lfloor x\rfloor+2$, then
$$y\geq \lfloor y\rfloor\geq \lfloor x\rfloor+2>x+1.$$

In general, it's a bad idea to use the same letter to refer to different variables (even if they vary among the same set); I've used $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ to clarify what's happening here.

Comment: They do not have the same size which I tried to make clear by the $2\lfloor\log_2(b + \Delta)\rfloor \ge \lfloor\log_2(a + \Delta)\rfloor$ or in other terms: $\log_2(a+\Delta)/\log_2(b+\Delta) \le 2$ that is the denominator is at least half the size of the numerator.

Comment: In the cases I listed, the denominator is at least half of the numerator. Unless I'm missing something, your condition stipulates that the numerator can't be too large compared to the denominator, instead of too small.

Comment: Sorry, my bad explanation, I'll try again. Assumption: if the errors of $a$ and/or $b$ are in $\{-1,0,1\}$, than the error of $x$ is also in $\{-1,0,1\}$. Taking $11/10$ as the case $a/b=x$, $\Delta = 0$; $10/9$ would be $(a-1)/(b-1)$ and $12/11 = (a+1)/(b+1)$. There are also $(a-1)/(b+1)$, $(a+1)/(b-1)$, $(a)/(b+1)$, $(a)/(b-1)$, $(a+1)/(b)$, $(a-1)/(b)$ if I forgot none. They work with your numbers and  $x=1$  except $\lfloor 10/11\rfloor = 0$, so the error of $x$ is in $\{-1,0\}$ which is in $\Delta$ and my assumption holds. But: is that the case in general?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi Ah -- that makes sense. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have to admit that, yes, indices would have helped a lot, sorry! Thank you very much for your patience! (Yes, I know, thank-you comments are frowned upon but I'm old-school and can't help it.) Added the missing indices to the question.